# Exporting animations for mutliple armatures not working as exptected

Tags: animation, armature, export, .fbx

I'm trying to export an FBX file with 2 armatures and corresponding animations but the export file does not contain all animations from both armatures.

I have rigged some fps arms and and a gun. The wrist bone from the hand is attached to the gun bone with an child-of constraint.

[image]


The animations work fine in blender. I can switch between them and the animations plays.
When I export to an FBX file I expect 4 clips. 2 for the arm armature and 2 for the  gun armature.
This works perfectly when only having one animation.

But what I end up with is having 2 animations for the gun armature and only one animation for the arm armature.

[image]

As you can see only 3 animations instead of 4 get created.
I need to have separate animatons because I want to use the arms for multiple weapons.

I've read that there might be a bug regarding this.
Or do I need to check for something else?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but then I came up with a solution of joining the mesh and armature of the gun to the mesh and armature of the arms. All the animations were exported properly and there were no problems with the animations as well.